# A large-display camera without apps

Tags: camera

I recently found out my dad struggles with wasting time at work, and wanted a phone without apps.  But the issue is, he uses his phone at work to take pictures; so he needs a camera with a large screen.  Is there something that can work?

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the list of all cameras out there, it turns out the only cameras with a screen larger than 3" generally fall into the following categories:

- Professional (read: expensive) cameras, e.g. [Zeiss ZX1](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1436638-REG/zeiss_zx1_digital_camera.html).
- Specialized cameras, e.g. [Fluke TiX-640](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/thermal-imaging/infrared-cameras/expert-series/fluke-tix640).
- Cameras with apps, e.g. [Samsung Galaxy Camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075H1H6GX).

However, there is a way to attach a [larger, external monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004LQ1QDE) to a DSLR camera, with sizes 5.5" and higher.  That would probably be the cheapest solution in this case.

However, in case the screen doesn't have to be 5.5", there is a way to get this even cheaper.  There is an abundance of [blackberry phones](https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=3203&idPhone2=4331&idPhone3=3926#diff-) with only basic apps, but with a screen larger than 3".